# Take user inputs, and add them?

Tags: python

So I am not too expierenced with python, and I was working on my project.

So basically what my program needs to do is ask the user how many items they are buying, then the program will ask for the price of each item, then calculate sales tax and add them together.

I don't want someone to do this all for me. But how exactly I be able to add all the inputs together?

Thanks

Comment: In programming, you will face many intimidating problems. The key to solving most of them is to break them down into smaller ones that can be easily solved or googled.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with an easier situation and build from there. Let's say that you already know all the items and their prices (i.e., the information is in variables). This solution is trivial: you just add them. You know, + sign.

Situation 2: let's say you know how many items there are, but you're missing one price. Solution: ask the user for the price. Google 'how to get user input in python' or similar.

Situation 3: let's say you know how many items there are, but you don't have any prices. Solution: set up a loop, like a for loop, to get user input. If you don't know what for loops are or how/why they're used, Google that.

Situation 4: Your problem. Same as situation 3, but you don't know how many items there are. What you need is a while loop. Again, don't know how to use while loops?--Google is your friend. But what should the while condition be? You want to keep asking WHILE the user has more items. The easiest way to do that is probably just to ask the user, 'do you have any more items?', and ask them to enter 'yes'. So you would want to do

```
while (moreItems == 'yes')
```

Tip: set the default moreItems value to 'yes' or use a do-while loop to make sure that the loop starts.

Tip: if you want to go the extra mile, make sure the while loop keeps going if the user spells it 'Yes' or 'y' or 'Y' instead of just 'yes'. To do that, use an OR in the while condition.

edit: I assumed this part was what you didn't know about. For the problem of adding sales tax and adding them all together, someone else has an excellent reply.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the answer, like many problems, involves an initial condition and then an operation that you iterate on.  In this case the initial sum is 0 and then you add to it.

Toward the beginning of you program you'll need something like:

```
sum = 0
```

Then inside the loop you'll need something like:

```
sum += item
```

In this case item has been calculated by your code with the sales tax added.

At the end of your program `sum` will have the total of all the items that you've added into it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code snippet:

```
size = input('How many inputs are you providing: ')
sumX = sum([input('Enter a value: ') for i in range(size)])
print "sum = ", sumX
```